# ASP.NET MVC issue resolving DbContext to a Derived class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

I do have a ASP.NET Core 2.0 application with `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

I added my Context `ApplicationDbContext` to the `Startup.cs` file:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(DefaultConnection));
```

My `ApplicationDbContext` inherits the `DbContext` class:

In a generic controller I require a `DbContext` class:

```
public GenericController(DbContext context){
```

However `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` cannot resolve the `DbContext` to the `ApplicationDbContext` registered service.

How can I inject the required `DbContext` class into my service class?

I'm able to change the `GenericController`, but the project where `GenericController` lies does not have reference to the `ApplicationDbContext`.

I'm developing a middleware, it should require DbContext that should be specialized in other projects. So the controller is in the middleware, it does not have a reference to the specialized class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by Just adding a Transient from derived class to parent class below the `AddContext` command

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(DefaultConnection));
services.AddTransient<DIADbContext,ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 2):

> the project where GenericController lies does not have reference to the `ApplicationDbContext`

This is 100% of your issue.

You either need to ensure that `ApplicationDbContext` is in a project that the services that use it can reference:

```
public GenericController(ApplicationDbContext context){
```

or you need to create an `IApplicationDbContext` that is implemented by `ApplicationDbContext` that can be referenced from the services that use it:

```
public GenericController(IApplicationDbContext context){
```

Injecting `DbContext` alone isn't going to cut it because it doesn't expose any of the tables that your application needs to use.

Comment: unfortunately I'm developing a middleware, it should require a specific DbContext that should be specialized in other projects. So the controller is in the middleware, it does not have a reference to the specialized class. only to the parent one. I think that i could resolve child classes.

Comment: If it doesn't have a reference to the concrete `ApplicationDbContext` then you will need to make a `IApplicationDbContext` interface in an assembly that is *shared* between the middleware assembly and the assembly that defines `ApplicationDbContext`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be to register the `DbContext` with a custom factory which will return the already registered `ApplicationDbContext` instance from the container:

```java
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(DefaultConnection));
services.AddScoped<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(s => s.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>());
```